# What does תושׁלכ"ע mean?

Tags: books-generally, acronyms

I saw the abbreviation תושׁלכ"ע in the introduction to a textbook ([*Classical Mechanics*, by Herbert Goldstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Mechanics_(Goldstein_book))). What does it stand for?

Comment: This question could be made more answerable by including the immediate context in which this abbreviation was used. Was it on its own? Was it part of a sentence or paragraph? Also, do you have reason to assume that this is a Judaism-related abbreviation?

Comment: You can see it in the snippet here: https://books.google.com/books?id=4YblBaliPeAC&q=Classical+Mechanics,+by+Herbert+Goldstein&dq=Classical+Mechanics,+by+Herbert+Goldstein&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS-9yVo-ngAhWKVN8KHcWPCs0Q6AEINDAC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you saw תושל**ב**״ע, rather than תושלכ״ע. As per [this handy book of abbreviations](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34968&st=&pgnum=270), תושלב״ע stands for תם ונשלם, שבח לא-ל בורא עולם, “Whole and complete, praise to G-d, the Creator of the world.”

(The linked book does not include this abbreviation with a כ.)

Comment: Based on the partial view linked in [Heshy's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100110/what-does-%d7%aa%d7%95%ef%ac%aa%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%a2-mean#comment334583_100110), it looks like the letter in question could indeed be either a ב or a כ.

Comment: On closer examination, this is exactly right. Thank you!
In the 3rd edition, the printing is much clearer, and the letter is obviously a ב
The preface to the second edition includes a complete quote of the pasuk from Daniel (2:23): https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.2.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
The preface to the 3rd edition includes a complete quotation of Tehillim 19:1, but in Greek